# Union 2 tables inner join on a third with 2 legacy applications

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a legacy Access front end connected to a mySQL database.  The legacy app has a lot of dangerous macros assigned to onclose triggers. I also have a web application under development running on the same database.  There are a couple of modules in the web app that are in production use.  My testing is being done on a separate development machine with a separate dedicated development version of the database.

A new module I'm installing into my web app comes with it's own set of tables.  It will happily exist in the same database but want's it's own copy of the data in it's own tables.  I hesitate to extensively modify the new tables or code base for that module.

There are a total of 6 tables that hold similar data for different objects in the legacy database.  I am only working on the 2 most important of those tables now.  The below represents only a very small subset of the columns in these 2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `agent` (
`age_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`age_agent_email_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`age_welcome_email_sent_y_or_n` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'No',
`age_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Active',
PRIMARY KEY (`age_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT=1854 ;
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prospecting_contacts` (
`psp_prospect_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`psp_prospecting_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Active',
`psp_prospect_email_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`psp_remove_from_email_marketing` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'No',
`psp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`psp_id`) USING BTREE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT=2050793 ;
```

There are several related tables that came with the new module.  I believe only one of them needs to be updated.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phplist_user_user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
`confirmed` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
`blacklisted` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
`bouncecount` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`entered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`uniqid` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`htmlemail` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
`subscribepage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`rssfrequency` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`passwordchanged` date DEFAULT NULL,
`disabled` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
`extradata` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
`foreignkey` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`optedin` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
KEY `foreignkey` (`foreignkey`),
KEY `idx_phplist_user_user_uniqid` (`uniqid`),
KEY `emailidx` (`email`),
KEY `enteredindex` (`entered`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

The php_list_user_user table would include data that is a result of this query:

```
SELECT `age_agent_email_address` AS `email` FROM `agent` 
    WHERE `age_status` = 'Active'
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT `psp_prospect_email_address` FROM `prospecting_contacts`
    WHERE `psp_prospecting_status` = 'Active'
```

The legacy access application updates the agent and prospecting_contacts tables.  The new module updates the php_list_user_user table.  I believe I can copy the information back and forth using TRIGGER.  But, I'm looking for a way that doesn't duplicate data.

I had thought of CREATE VIEW, but the mysql manual says that unions and joins break it's update ability. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html

So, is there a way to update these 3 tables without duplicating data?  Or should I just duplicate the email addresses and use TRIGGERs on INSERT and UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something clever with foreign keys though they are more attuned to keeping tables consistent rather than preventing duplicates. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

It may seem counter-intuitive but another solution would be to maintain a lookup table that indicated where a specific value could be found. You could join with all three of the (sub)tables to prevent duplicates.

A trigger would work too.

Comment: I'm not a fan of storing the same data in 2 places.  Also, the ultimate goal is to move away from the legacy Access frontend.  Once that's done I can begin to normalize the legacy portion of the db. Foreign keys are difficult while the legacy frontend is still in use.  I didn't build it.  I am only just getting familiar with the various triggers built into it.  One missed placed foreign key with a cascade could do some real damage to the production db.    The developer that built it used a lot of large delete queries to sync data between tables.  But, I've been warned off of the Access app.

Comment: @ethrbuny, could you explain the lookup table?  I've been approaching this from the direction of a stored query.  Perhaps a lookup table could get me past the unupdateability of a view with a union and joins.

Comment: What would happen if you left join the three tables together when looking for a specific addr? You'd avoid duplicates and could probably get the relevant info too.

Comment: I think I've decided just to copy the data over and use TRIGGER to keep it synced.  I'm just not finding another solution that would allow these 2 radically different applications to manipulate the same data.